# Can't save a figure of 920px width in matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I ran into a problem whilst trying to save a 920px width png from numpy data. One column is missing. It seems only this width causes the problem (I tried some others and the problem did not happen). MWE:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
a1 = np.zeros((919, 100))
a2 = np.zeros((920, 100))
a3 = np.zeros((921, 100))
plt.imsave('test1.png', a1)
plt.imsave('test2.png', a2)
plt.imsave('test3.png', a3)
```

The resulting images all have a height of 100, but the widths are:

- test1: 919
- test2: **919**
- test3: 921

What is happening here?

---

Versions:

- matplotlib: 1.4.3
- numpy: 1.9.2

Comment: just to add to this: This is reproducible in mpl 1.5.1 and numpy 1.10.4, and also occurs for `jpg` as well as `png`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a matplotlib bug: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/4280. Apparently it was fixed in February 2016 (maybe in https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/5718), but I don't think there has been a release since the bug was fixed in the master branch.

A work-around is to use the argument `dpi=1` in the `imsave` function, e.g.:

```
plt.imsave("foo.png", a, dpi=1)
```

but a DPI of 1 might confuse some software that reads the PNG file.